# GetListItemChangesSinceToken query returns "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: development

The following statement returns "Value does not fall within the expected range." when the query argument is filled in. If it is set to null, the call works fine.

```
XmlElement data = (XmlElement)listsObject.GetListItemChangesSinceToken(listGUID, null, query, viewFields, null, queryOptions, null, contains);
```

The query argument contains the following code:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Status" />
      <ValueType Type="Text">Approved</ValueType>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="Status" />
  </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Did you try it without defining query (pass null)? Column `Status` is OOTB column or?

Answer (score 2):

<del>Have to tried removing the `<Query>` tag from the query text? Also, have you tried putting the `OrderBy` before the `Where`? Sometimes SharePoint doesn't like queries like that</del>

Have you tried changing the order of the OrderBy and Where tags? According to this [blog post](http://blog.henryong.com/2009/06/29/the-ordering-of-your-caml-query-matters/) and my own personal experience, you should put the OrderBy tag **before** the Where tag.

Comment: -1 It's webservice so `<Query>` is needed

Comment: I don't think I deserve a downvote, maybe the Query is required if you say so, but the order of the CAML query definitely makes a difference: http://blog.henryong.com/2009/06/29/the-ordering-of-your-caml-query-matters/ The OP posted a query with the OrderBy clause after the Where clause.  It's at least worth a try

Comment: Why didn't you included this link in answer? Edit your answer, include link in it and you will receive up vote because you provided useful info. And don't post multiple answers. Edit existing one. Your other answer is more comment then real answer.

Comment: And yes. If I look at it now it is not a -1 answer. Still it was only answer when I down voted it because it looked that you posted it without thinking and you provided IMO useless info.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure that fields you are using in `OrderBy` are included in the SPSiteDataQuery.ViewFields property?

If not, could you please paste the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

At [Lists.GetListItemChangesSinceToken Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitemchangessincetoken%28v=office.12%29.aspx) it says:

> Note:
>   The GetListItemChangesSinceToken method fails for lists with unique item permissions if the PermMask field is not explicitly requested: `<FieldRef Name="PermMask"/>`

Could this be your issue?

Answer (score 0):

[GetListItemChangesSinceToken MSDN Reference article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitemchangessincetoken%28office.12%29.aspx) says:

> The query parameter is not intended to be used with the contains parameter.

So, just remove your contains parameter, and it should be ok.

Comment: He's not using contains is he?

Comment: He is. If you would read the question intently, you could notice `contains` variable passed to `GetListItemChangesSinceToken` (it is the last one)

Comment: Oh yes you're right :)